# MacOS Terminal defaulting to -bash instead of bash

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, settings, default

So macOS is now using zsh but I set mine to use bash (updated from brew) using `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash` when I restart my terminal the bash that shows up is `-bash` in the title which I double check the output of `echo $0`. When I type `bash` I get another shell `bash` verified by the same command `echo $0`. I want the `bash` to be my default but `-bash` seems to be the default and I'm not sure why or how to change it.

Comment: IIRC the leading - means it's a login shell.

Comment: even on zsh when you do `echo $0` you get the (-) hyphen before the shell name `-zsh`. When you type 'bash', I think that bash shell is SHLVL=2, a child of the parent bash.